# Android MediaPlayer cannot play files that contain '#' character in the file name using Uri.parse("...#.mp3")

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

My media player works with playing all other file names I have tried except with file names that have a '#' in them

```
MediaPlayer m_mediaplayer;
```

...

```
m_mediaplayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, Uri.parse(musicFile));
```

where musicFile is a string to the filename = "/storage/emulated/0/Music/ASOT 643 (2013-12-12) (Inspiron)/31 Geert Huinink & Mike van Fabio - The Kingdom [Future Favorite #641].mp3"

m_mediaplayer returns null...if I remove the '#' from the file name it works like all the other songs. It seems to be the Uri.parse(musicFile) which gets confused with the hashtag it seems.

Any help would be appreciated in solving this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're passing it a URI.  A # in a URI is an anchor tag.  SO Uri.parse thinks the filename ends at the #, and the rest is a fragment.  Basically, you can't use Uri.parse.  I'd look at using Uri.fromFile instead

Edit:  found a better method than fromParts-  fromFile

Comment: thanks...this is what I used, for clarification: m_mediaplayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, Uri.fromFile(new File(musicFile)));

Comment: Thanks! I had similar problem with character "?" and this works for me too.